# Can user privilege of docker container impact permission of host machine on mounted volume in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have `docker-compose.yml` as below，

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: centos/mysql-56-centos7:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=111111
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
      - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql/data
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

`centos/mysql-56-centos7` is a image from Docker Hub. I use `docker-compose up` to start the container, but it always fail, the cause is:

```
Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/data/cdef45a5817c.lower-test
```

full info:

```
    Creating network "mysql_default" with the default driver
    Creating mysql ... ^M
    ^[[1A^[[2K^MCreating mysql ... ^[[32mdone^[[0m^M^[[1BAttaching to mysql
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m => sourcing 20-validate-variables.sh ...
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m => sourcing 25-validate-replication-variables.sh ...
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m => sourcing 30-base-config.sh ...
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m ---> 16:39:17     Processing basic MySQL configuration files ...
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m => sourcing 60-replication-config.sh ...
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m => sourcing 70-s2i-config.sh ...
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m ---> 16:39:17     Processing additional arbitrary  MySQL configuration provided by s2i ...
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m => sourcing 40-paas.cnf ...
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m => sourcing 50-my-tuning.cnf ...
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m ---> 16:39:17     Initializing database ...
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m ---> 16:39:17     Running mysql_install_db --rpm --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/data
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 0 [Note] Ignoring --secure-file-priv value as server is running with --bootstrap.
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 0 [Note] /opt/rh/rh-mysql56/root/usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.38) starting as process 30 ...
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/data/a5d11f4146dd.lower-test
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/data/a5d11f4146dd.lower-test
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 32.0M
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 7f1048c42840  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m InnoDB: the directory.
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 7f1048c42840  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m InnoDB: the directory.
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [ERROR] InnoDB: Creating or opening ./ibdata1 failed!
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [ERROR] Aborting
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [Note] Binlog end
    ^[[36mmysql    |^[[0m 2020-01-10 16:39:17 30 [Note] /opt/rh/rh-mysql56/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

If I remove this line `/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql/data` from `docker-compose.yml`, the container can be started normally.

I run `docker-compose up` with root privilege on host machine, how can there be permission problem? I don't know with what user privilege the MySQL process is started within the docker container, but how can that impact the permission of host machine?

---

other information:

on the host machine, it seems selinux is not enabled

```
# getenforce
Disabled
```

I chmod the mysql folder, so

```
# ls -l /data
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 6 Jan  9 15:28 mysql
```

Comment: This sounds like an SE Linux issue. Look at the [discussion here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288616/permission-denied-on-accessing-host-directory-in-docker). Based on what they are discussing there, you can try appending a `:z` to the problematic mounts like this: `/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql/data:z` and see if that helps.

Comment: @JakeGould `getenforce` result is `Disabled `,  it seems that SELinux is not enabled. I tried your solution, it doesn't work and still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the MySQL user inside the Docker container does not have permissions to write to the `/data/mysql` directory on the host filesystem. This has nothing to do with you running `docker compose` as root. The `mysql` daemon is started as the`mysql` user inside the container, hence it has those privileges.

To fix this issue, change the ownership of the `/data/mysql` directory on the host filesystem:

```
sudo chown -R 27 /data/mysql
```

27 is the numeric UID of the `mysql` user inside the Docker container. Use the number instead of the `mysql` name, as the UID might be different for the `mysql` user on the host filesystem, but the actual permissions are checked by UID number.

*Don't make a directory `rwx` or `777` unless there is a very good reason to do so*

Comment: thx, but the solution does't work, still the same issue

Comment: BTW, how do you know the UID is 27?

Comment: I started the docker container and checked the UID of the `mysqld` process.